# CSS transform transition not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I've done some research and couldn't seem to fix it with other people's solutions. I'm trying animate the dropdown description box when hovering the .cols container.

I have the following codes:

```css
    .cols-wrapper .cols .desc {
        min-height: 150px !important;
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 285px;
        padding: 10px 25px 25px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.3s ease all;
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    
    .cols-wrapper .cols:hover .desc {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
```

```html
<div class="cols-wrapper">
  <div class="cols col1">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <div class="desc">
      <p>Description goes here</p>
      <a href="#" class="cta">Submit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Could anyone please give it a crack?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `display` parameter from both:

```css
.cols-wrapper .cols .desc {
        min-height: 150px !important;
        position: absolute;
        background-color: #fff;
        width: 285px;
        padding: 10px 25px 25px;
        box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        z-index: 99;
        opacity: 0;
        transition: 0.3s ease all;
        transform: translateY(-30px);
    }
    
    .cols-wrapper .cols:hover .desc {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateY(0px);
    }
```

```html
<div class="cols-wrapper">
  <div class="cols col1">
    <img src="image.jpg">
    <h4>Title</h4>
    <div class="desc">
      <p>Description goes here</p>
      <a href="#" class="cta">Submit</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice!! Thank you. It worked. Not sure why I'd have that when I was using opacity already.